# Increase number to be equal to another keeping ratio

Tags: fractions

Sales team A consists of `100 people with 40 sales`. Sales team B consist of `50 people with 25 sales`.

I would say that sales team B overall had a better performance in making sales considering its proportionate size to sales team A. I would like to graph this but I first need the two numbers to be equal. Increasing the smaller number while keeping the ratio.

For example: `100/40 and 50/25 should be converted to 100/40 100/50`. If anybody knows the formula for doing this I would really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Hace you not just written down the two correct formulas `100/40` `100/50` yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @KurtG. said, you have converted the ratios properly yourself. Assuming you want help with graphing it, here is a possibility of what you need to graph-

Say, $x=$ number of people in the sales team, $y=$ number of sales. For the first team, say the straight line $y=mx$ represents the number of sales$(y)$ for different numbers of people$(x)$. Then,
$$40=100m\Rightarrow m=\frac{40}{100}=0.4$$
Similarly for team 2, if $y=cx$ is the required line then,
$$25=50c\Rightarrow c=\frac{25}{50}=0.5$$
The corresponding graph is, as follows (red line for team 1, blue for team 2). Also, since the number of people and number of sales can't be negative, we only look at the first quadrant.

[image]

Clearly, the blue line is above the red line everywhere i.e., team 2 has higher relative sales than team 1 implying that team 2 has a better performance. Note that, $m,c$ are simply the ratio of sales per team to number of people in the team. A higher ratio is indicative of a better performance, hence the observation.